# How to find root of two implicit functions in Python, without using fsolve for the set of equations

Tags: python, root

I am dealing with a set of several non-linear equations that I was able to reduce analytically to set of two implicit equations with two variables. Now I wish to find roots of those equations using Brent's method. I would like to pass one function as an argument to another and solve the equation for variable 2 depending on every variable 1.

In mathematical terms I wish to solve: f(x,y) and g(x,y) in this way f(x,g(x)).

Simplify example of what I wish to do can be presented here.

Instead of:

```
import scipy.optimize
from scipy.optimize import fsolve  

def equations(p): 
     y,z = p 
     f1 = -10*z + 4*y*z - 5*y + 4*z**2 - 7 
     f2 = 2*y*z + 5*y - 3 
     return (f1,f2)
```

and solve it by:

> y, z = fsolve(equations,[0,19])

I wish to write something like that:

```
def func2(x, y):
    f2= 2*y*x + 5*y - 3
    return brentq(f2, -5, 5) 
def func(x,y):  
    y = func2(x,y)
    return -10*x + 4*x*y - 5*y + 4*x**2 - 7

sol, = brentq(lambda x: func(x, func2), -5, 5)
```

I wish to ask for help in how to pass a function as an argument for this particular purpose and explain what am I doing wrong. I am new to Python and maybe there is a better way to ensure precise solution to my problem.